# Does the Messiah have to come from Solomon or his successor?

Tags: messiah, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, king-david, king-solomon

Is him being a descendant of Solomon accepted as fact or is it only speculated to be the case?
Is this based off of the section in [1 Kings chapter 2 verse 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a02.htm), where David tells Solomon how G-d promised him that there will always be someone of his line on the throne, as long as they follow G-d?

The thing is, David doesn't mention Solomon by name here. So if you take it at face value, it's talking about any descendant of David. Solomon wasn't the only surviving son of David with progeny, right?

Is there another passage that cements Solomon's role as the Messiah's ancestor? If there is, then how do we know that the Messiah would come from Rehoboam's line? Solomon [probably had tons of children](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/how-many-children-did-king-solomon-have) besides him.

Edit: Since this is technically a duplicate, can anyone answer the part about Rehoboam in the original question that has been linked up top?

Comment: I address the issue in the answer to the duplicate question. As each king was crowned, that eliminated his collateral relatives as possibilities, Just as Shlomo being crowned eliminated his brothers as possibilities.As a result, the line continues through Zerubavel and beyond (though we do not **know** who is the current possibility).

Comment: @sabbahillel I see. Is there any source that indicates only one line must be the source for Messiah rather than potentially any of Solomon's descendants? Is it that "A king can only come from a King"? If that's the case, there hasn't been a King or leader of the Davidic line in recent times that we know of who we can assign even a technical label of King to. Which is why it seems strange that he should come from a specific line that has been forgotten over time.

Comment: That just leads to what might have happened after Zerubavel. Just because we do not know, does not mean that the actual line is gone. Hashem knows who it is.

Comment: I guess at a certain point, you just have to wait and see, right? Haha.

Comment: I think this question has a different thrust than the one it supposedly duplicates. I believe this question is asking, "Does Moshiach really *have* to come from such and such a line" rather than "Which line does Moshiach 'have' to come from?" (In other words, the emphasis here is on whether there is any possibility for these prophecies about Moshiach /not/ to be true.) If so, the question could be improved, but I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Since the line must go through Zerubavel, then Rechavam is the ancestor it comes from.